linux sed how to replace part of a line without breaking indentation in a text file
I would like to solve this issue. I have a file in linux that is going to be later read as a yaml file, so indententation is very important. I would like to find once specific line and replace only part of it.
::: rest of the file :::
first:
    second:
        third:
            variable: [1, 2, 3]
::: rest of the file :::

what I would like to do is replace only the last element of the array. Is it possible to find the pattern ", 3]" and replace it by for example ", 10]" without breaking the indentation ? So far I think the command sed can help, but i did not find a way not to break the structure of the file.
What I know for sure that there is

only one instance of "variable: " in the file and the numbers in the array could be either integers or float but they are numbers not letters. and i don't know the numbers in advance.

Thanks if you have any pointers.

like so? is the underlying issue more general or is this a one - time thing?

Why would sed even change the indentation? It's going to do a search and replace. If you are not replacing the indentation part, then you're not changing the indentation.

it's a one time thing. but what if in other lines in the file (it's a big file) there is another ", 3]" would i risk to change that as well ? is it possible to speciy the number of the line it should only work on?

Please [edit] your question and show your code that broke the structure and the resulting output. If the problem occurs only with a longer example, then extend the example. Please add all information to the question, comments are for asking for clarification.

find the pattern ", 3]" and replace it by for example ", 10]" as stated in your question is a very different requirement from that describe in a comment - i am not sure that there is only one instance of , 3] . i only know there is one instance of "variable: " thus it should be my working point. and i don't know which numbers are going to be there in advance. I only want to force the thirt element to be ; 10]. Please fix your question.

Also make it clear if you want to modify the 3rd number on the line or the last number on the line.

Use a yaml parser like yq:
$ yq -i '.first.second.third.variable[-1] = 10' -- file
$ cat file
first:
  second:
    third:
      variable: [1, 2, 10]


this is amazing! i think i will use this one. it is way better than sed

Using GNU sed for -E and \s:
$ sed -E 's/(\s*variable:.*[, ]).*]/\110]/' file
::: rest of the file :::
first:
    second:
        third:
            variable: [1, 2, 10]
::: rest of the file :::


If there's only on e instance of , 3] in your code, this should do the trick:
% sed -i 's;, 3];, 10];' name-of-file

If you want to generalize it a bit more, you could replace 3 with \d\+ for 1 or more digits or \w\+ for one or more non-whitespace characters.

i am not sure that there is only one instance of , 3]   . i only know there is one instance of "variable: " thus it should be my working point. and i don't know which numbers are going to be there in advance. I only want to force the thirt element to be ; 10]

i am thinking if it is not easier to find the number of the said line. and then work on this specific line.

\d and \w are Perl extensions which are not portably supported in sed. Some implementations support them, yes; but the code you write might not run on others.

I'm actually not sure if ANY sed (or any other tool that uses BREs or EREs) supports \d.
